# Restrictions don't work for createAlias

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Here is my problem:

I want to do something like this query via hibernate criteria

```
select employee.name, employee.surname, department.name, position.name, department_position.end_date 
    from employee, department_position, department, position 
    where employee.id = department_position.employee_id
        and department_position.department_id = department.id
        and department_position.position_id = position.id
    and department_position.end_date is null
```

I have class `Employee` mapped to employee table

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Set<DepartmentPosition> positions;
}
```

and `DepartmentPosition` (with all setters and getters of course)

```
public class DepartmentPosition {
    private int id;
    private Department department;
    private Position position;
    private Employee employee;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
}
```

And I'm using this criteria

```
session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
    .createAlias("Positions", "pos")
    .add(Restrictions.isNull("pos.EndDate"));
```

Only 1 employee in my db matches this query (and he has 1 position with `null` `endDate`), but in resulting list it is repeated 3 times (looks like because this employee has 3 positions total)

How can i fix this?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use restriction like `Restrictions.isNull("Employee.Position.EndDate")` - you did not specified in `Restriction` that `Position` is a property of `Employee`.

Comment: No need to specify that. The `createALias` method works on root object.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the criteria on positions object then use projection to get the employee.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DepartmentPosition.class)
    .add(Restrictions.isNull("endDate"));

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("employee")));
criteria.setProjection(projList);
```